# Proving set equality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was looking online for some examples to aid my understanding of set equality and I'm confused on this question.

$A = \{x\mid 0 ≤ x ≤ 50 \quad\text{and}\quad  x=4n^2 +11, \quad n\in N\}$.

$B = \{n^2 + 11\mid n\in N,n ≤ 6\}$

Is $A = B$?

I understand I need to show $A$ is a subset of $B$ and $B$ is a subset of $A$, But I get stuck here.

Comment: Where do you get stuck specifically? You are right that showing A and B to be subsets of each other works.

Comment: @Dasherman - I get stuck on how to go about showing the subsets as a proof?

Comment: For every element of A, show that it must also be in B and vice versa.

Comment: So, I would need to list out all the elements of A and B and see if they are in each other? - What about proving it with arbitrary sets?

Comment: No, just use "Let x be an element of A....[here you prove the stuff]... Thus x must be in B" and the other way around.

Comment: @Dasherman - Okay I understand you, but the proof bit is the bit in which i get stuck as Im not sure if I'm doing it right

Answer (score 3):

$A \neq B$ because $12 \in B$, but $\not \in A$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you did that?

Comment: Take $n=1$.Thus,  $12 \in B$. But there is no $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $12 \in A$.

Comment: Great thanks. If i would assume there are two arbitrary sets A and B - how would I show that they are equal? or is that not possible?

Comment: Yes! You should show that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$.

Comment: through arbitrary sets how would that be possible to show a subset b and b subset a ?

Comment: I think there is no a general method for that. It depends on the sets.

Comment: @RandomMath $A\subseteq B\iff \forall x\in A(x\in B)$.

Answer (score 1):

Just by explicit computation we have $A=\{15,27,47\}$ and $B=\{ 12, 15, 20, 27, 36, 47\}$.

Hence $A \subset B$. Since $|A| < |B|$, we have $A \neq B$.

If you want to make it more complicated, note that
$4 n^2 +11 \le 50 $ **iff** $|n| \le { \sqrt{39} \over 2}$, hence
$A = \{ 4 n^2+11 | n \in \mathbb{N}, n \le 3 \} = \{ (2n)^2+11 | n \in \mathbb{N}, n \le 3 \}$.

Now note that $\{ 2n | n \in \mathbb{N}, n \le 3 \} \subset \{ n | n \in \mathbb{N}, n \le 6 \} $, hence we have
$A \subset B$. (And again, $|A| < |B|$, so we have $A \neq B$.)